# Sharing sub-folders as well

Tags: 10.04, file-sharing, shared-folders

I am new to ubuntu, I have ubuntu 10.04 and want to share the video\music files with my xtremer. I was using this guide ([Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/networking-shares.html)) but i want also to share the sub folders.

now I can see all the folders but not there contents, how can I share the folder with all is sub folders and there contents?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

did you try after sharing to right click the parent folder, go in *permissions* tab and click on apply permissions on contents?

Hope it helps

Comment: I cant find this option :/, maybe its because I am using the netbook edition